# VBoxManage: The given path [UUID] is not fully qualified

Tags: virtualbox

```
$ vboxmanage clonehd foo.vmdk bar.vmdk
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Clone hard disk created in format 'VMDK'.
UUID: f9dffd47-4907-44a5-b3f9-40eba3953d24
$ vboxmanage showhdinfo "f9dffd47-4907-44a5-b3f9-40eba3953d24"
VBoxManage: error: The given path 'f9dffd47-4907-44a5-b3f9-40eba3953d24' is 
not fully qualified
```

I can just use the path name, but it is annoying. What do I need to make the hd commands work with an UUID?